# Remove a zero from date using format 'm.d.y' in PHP?

Tags: php, date

Hello I was wondering how to remove a zero from a date when it is given in the following format `m.d.y`. So if I get the following date `6.02.13` I want it to become `6.2.13`. How would I accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: read [date in manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: `$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m.d.y','6.02.13'); echo $myDate->format('n.j.y');`

Comment: just look at `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php`

Answer (score 8):

Instead of format `m.d.y` you can use format `n.j.y`.

Comment: Those are is the correct formats that I want to change between. But @MikeBaker Gave me an example through code on how to do it so I'll each give you an up vote to split the profit evenly on who helped me the most.

Comment: @camelCaseD: if you already got formated date from somewhere, then Mike's example is best to use. My answer was for scenario, where you are the one who is formating the date.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php echo date('j m Y'); ?>
```

to get this result: `6.06.2013` instead of `06.06.2013`

or:

```
<?php echo date('j n Y'); ?>
```

to get this result: `6.6.2013`